# Ignite clientMode vs Thin Client

Tags: ignite

I see a two ways to setup client in Ignite:

1. then Ignition.start(IgniteConfiguration.clientMode = true)
2. Ignition.startClient

but can't find any details about the first mode in docs.

What's the difference between two ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one will start a [thick client node](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/clustering#overview) that joins the cluster via an internal protocol, receive all of the cluster-wide updates such as topology changes, and support all of the Ignite APIs.

While the second one will start a [Java Thin Client](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/java-thin-client) which is a lightweight client that connects to the existing cluster node and performs all operations through that node. The thin client does not become a part of the cluster topology.

You can find more details regarding the difference between the client types [here](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/getting-started/concepts#thick-vs-thin-clients).

Answer (score 0):

The former starts a thick client, the latter a thin client.

A thick client is (mostly) a server node that’s configured not to store data or run compute tasks. So you get the full API, but it’s relatively heavy-weight.

A [thin client](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/getting-started-with-thin-clients) does not become a cluster node, so it’s smaller and simpler. There are a few APIs that are not available.

If you can use a thin client, that’s likely the correct solution.